# Python - Tesseract

Tags: python, tesseract

I am trying to extract text from an Image using Tesseract module in Python:

```
from pytesser import *
image = Image.open('fnord.tif')  # Open image object using PIL
print image_to_string(image)     # Run tesseract.exe on image
fnord
```

But am getting the following error:

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Python34\lib\pytesser\pytesser.py", line 49, in  image_file_to_string
text = image_to_string(im, cleanup)
File "C:\Python34\lib\pytesser\pytesser.py", line 31, in image_to_string
call_tesseract(scratch_image_name, scratch_text_name_root)
File "C:\Python34\lib\pytesser\pytesser.py", line 24, in call_tesseract
errors.check_for_errors()
File "C:\Python34\lib\pytesser\errors.py", line 15, in check_for_errors
raise Tesser_General_Exception(text)
pytesser.errors.Tesser_General_Exception: Tessedit:Error:Usage:Tessedit      imagename outputbase [configfile [[+|-]varfile]...]

Signal_exit 25 ABORT. LocCode: 3  AbortCode: 0
```

Comment: Looks like the `tesseract.exe` is being called with the wrong commandline... it may be a bug in the library.

Comment: `pip install pytesseract` not `pytesser`

Comment: It looks like you're supposed to supply a string not a PIL image.

Answer (score 0):

Is this on a Mac?

Try editing the `call_tesseract` function. Change:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(args)
retcode = proc.wait()
```

to:

```
retcode = subprocess.call(args)
```

Answer (score 0):

Download the 2mb file at:

https://code.google.com/archive/p/pytesser/downloads

Copy the path of tesseract.exe and then open file pytesseract.py 
there is a variable in the file by the name 'tesseract_cmd' which holds the path for the file tesseract.exe. Store the copied path in the variable.

Run your program and your error will be no more.

Answer (score 0):

I personally recommend [pytesseract](https://github.com/madmaze/pytesseract) (pytesser and pytesseract are different) as pytesser have stopped with only one version.

so just pip install the pytesseract package

Note: Python 2 will not have good support on foreign language extraction, so better go with python 3.